# How can I test calling a contract function from a specific address?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Here's my contract:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract NoteDrop {
    string public text = "Hello, world!";
    address public lastPoster;

    event NewText(
        string text,
        address lastPoster
    );

    constructor() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    function setText(string memory _text) public {
        text = _text;
        lastPoster = msg.sender;
        emit NewText(_text, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

```js
contract('NoteDrop', () => {
  let noteDropContract;

  beforeEach(async() => {
    noteDropContract = await NoteDropContract.new();
  })

  describe('lastPoster', async() => {
    it('is changed automatically', async() => {
      await noteDropContract.setText("something", {from: "XXXXX"});
      const lastPoster = await noteDropContract.lastPoster();
      assert.equal(lastPoster, "XXXXX");
    })
  })
})
```

I would like to test that the `lastPoster` field gets updated on the contract to the address that last called the `setText` function.

What I don't know is how to generate (or fetch) an address that has a balance. I need that to call `setText` `from` that specific address, so that I can then `assert` that `noteDrop.lastPoster()` equals that sender address.

What am I missing? How can I generate an address to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution quickly. The answer is that the contract test function can take an optional parameter, `accounts`:

```js
contract('NoteDrop', (accounts) => {
```

You can then use this down in your tests like so:

```js
it('is changed automatically', async() => {
  await noteDropContract.setText("something", {from: accounts[0]});
  const lastPoster = await noteDropContract.lastPoster();
  assert.equal(lastPoster, accounts[0]);
})
```